# TD height issues in the table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am having a table with the below structure -

```
**HTML:**
    <table>
        <tr class="table_row row_over">
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="check_data_1" class="check_box" /></td>
          <td>
              Data1
          </td>
          <td>$0.000</td>
          <td>$0.000</td>
          <td>$0.000</td>
          <td>
              <span class="row_controls">
                  <a href="#" class="icon_22 icon_delete">
                     <span>Delete</span>
                  </a>
              </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

**CSS:**
.icon_delete {
    background-position: 0 0px;
}
.icon_22 {
    background-image: url("../images/icon_sprite.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;    
    width: 24px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Problem:
Height of the TD increases based on icon height. It increases the TD height and mis-allign with other td, where as I have still space left at bottom of TD.

Expected as attached image herewith:

[image]

Comment: have you tried vertical-align:center; to the TD. but you have to make the <A> size same as the background-image size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you would like to align the icon to the middle, I would do it like this:

change the icon's css to `display: block`:

```
.icon_22 {
    background-image: url("../images/icon_sprite.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    height: 24px;    
    width: 24px;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Then, and because you're using a `td`, specify a class to that `td` so it aligns vertically in the middle:

```
<td class="alignMiddle">
```

and the CSS:

```
.alignMiddle {
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: If I make display:block, icons are breaking into separate rows. Applying the vertical alignment to middle is solving the issue.
Thanks a lot for you time.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `.row_controls` is `position: relative;` and the icon is `position: absolute;`, it's going to be part of the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#normal-flow) and therefore occupy space.

Currently you are using `inline-block`. You need to pull it out of the normal flow by using positioning or floating techniques.

Try the following as a base.

```
.row_controls {
  position: relative;
}

.icon_22 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Sorry to say...this is not working for me. Inside TD all the positioning seems to be failing for me. Any idea Why?

Comment: The `td` alone is not *positionable*. That's why you need to position the wrapping `span`. I'm not sure your other styles, so it's difficult to say if there's a conflict. However, what I provided should be a base.